# Python: multiply numpy arrays with shapes (n,m,l) and (n,m) to obtain a (n,m,l) array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am working with two numpy arrays a and b with a.shape=(n,m,l) and b.shape=(n,m) and I would like to multiply them to obtain c with c.shape=(n,m,l) as equivalent to

```
for ei in range(a.shape[0]):
    for ej in range(a.shape[1]):
        c[ei, ej, :] = b[ei, ej] * a[ei, ej, :]
```

but with a more compact syntax similar to np.multiply to multiply two arrays with equal shapes. Is this possible?

Comment: Read up on broadcasting: `c = a * b[:,:,None]`

Answer (score 0):

Either (as per @PaulBroderson in the comments)

```
c = a * b[:, :, None]
```

Or using `np.einsum`:

```
c = np.einsum('ij, ijk -> ijk', a, b)
```